What would dissolve Plasticina modeling Clay completely into liquid?
I am doing a project and want to dissolve non drying modeling clay into liquid running form to spray it onto a metal application. Based on my findings it is made out of oil/lanolin/petroleum jelly and wax like substances. What can I use to completely dissolve it and keep it the liquid like form. I have tried acetone/paint thinner/ xylene/ mineral spirits. It dissolves slightly but not completely to what i need it to be. In Europe they have Solvent 646 which turns it into does the job, however in US what can I use to dissolve it?  Appreciate the help!

If Solvent 646 is adequate for your needs, make it yourself from the ingredients (see also house.decorexpro.com).
The following are the ingredients listed in those references:

Toluol 50%
Butanol 15%;
Butyl acetate 10%
Ethanol 10%
Ethyl cellosolve 8%;
Acetone 7%.

That said, this would not completely dissolve Plasticine, which contains insoluble calcium compounds.
There also will be considerable hazards using this solvent:

The ingredients are all somewhat toxic, both as liquid and as vapor. Consult the chemical safety data sheets for their use.
All are highly flammable.
All pose environmental hazards, and disposal issues. (Even ethanol -- I was saddened when local bakeries were required to reduce emissions due to it's adding to photochemical smog. The smell of baking bread had been so wonderful. sigh)

